# Wicket: Palette set default selected

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to implement a palette. I try to set a default selected list but it's empty.

myLists:

```
    // here I get a Set of the categorys which are already in that group
    Set<Category> selectedCategorysSet = new HashSet<Category>();
    selectedCategorysSet = group.getCategorys();

    // here I get all categorys exists
    List<Category> listCategory = new ArrayList<Category>();
    listCategory = catDao.getAll(Category.class);

    List<Category> selectedCats = new ArrayList<Category>();
    List<Category> tmpList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    // the palette doesnt accept an Set so I added the set to a List
    selectedCats.addAll(selectedCategorysSet); 

    // here I delete every Category from the whole List which is already selected (stored in a temporary list)
    for(Category catList:listCategory){
        for(Category cat:selectedCategorysSet){
            if(cat.getCategoryId() == catList.getCategoryId()){
                tmpList.add(catList);
            }
        }
    }

    listCategory.removeAll(tmpList);

    /*
       two multiple select boxes which switches items between each other
    */
    IChoiceRenderer<Category> renderer = new ChoiceRenderer<Category>("title","categoryId");

    final Palette<Category> palette = new Palette<Category>("palette",
            new ListModel<Category>(selectedCats),
            new CollectionModel<Category>(listCategory),
            renderer, 10, false);
```

I already debugged that code, it works but my selected values are empty.

Here is a picture of my debugged variables: [image: debugged]

but the selected field is still empty!

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not delete *`every Category from the whole List which is already selected`*.

Palette component must store whole list of values in it's `choicesModel` which is `listCategory` in your code.

So, just remove following code from your implementation:

```java
for(Category catList:listCategory){
    for(Category cat:selectedCategorysSet){
        if(cat.getCategoryId() == catList.getCategoryId()){
            tmpList.add(catList);
        }
    }
}

listCategory.removeAll(tmpList);
```

Comment: ahw, ok got it. I thought totaly wrong. Thanks! I dont get into models.. May I asked u something to a problem based on this?

Comment: @monti, of course you can. I think this is more about `Palette` model's usage, and not about models itself. You always should look into framework's source code for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks alot! I store all selected `categorys` to an object called `group`. I got a panel where I just list every `group` I got. It works fine till I save more than one category to a group. It shows me the same group equal to the size of the categorys I stored.
A picture of my list: [Link](http://i.imgur.com/c8CCudj.png)

In my panel I get the values of my db like this: `List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<Group>();
groupList = groupDao.getAll(Group.class);`

Inside my DB is just ONE entry

Comment: @monti, a little hard to understand panel's behavior. It seems you better ask new question with more info about your panel impl. If you add another category to group (check it is actually there) and panel's list is not updated, then it's likely about your model (read about `PropertyModel` and try to use it). If you add category and it is not saved in db, then check your `save` method. Also, check your `groupList` is accessible to add/remove items(it could be unmodifiable).

Comment: mh I think its better to ask another question. Thanks for your help anyway!